# JavaScript regular expression, return everything before and after a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have the need to return a string (filename) without certain data, example strings are:

- eng_somerset_yeovil_montacute-house_962.jpg
- eng_south-yorkshire_barnsley_wentworth-castle_0.jpg
- eng_staffordshire_harriseahead_mow-cop-castle_1329317.jpg
- eng_somerset_weston-super-mare_marine-lake-walkway_29113.jpg

These example strings need to be returned as the following:

- eng_somerset_yeovil_montacute-house.jpg
- eng_south-yorkshire_barnsley_wentworth-castle.jpg
- eng_staffordshire_harriseahead_mow-cop-castle.jpg
- eng_somerset_weston-super-mare_marine-lake-walkway.jpg

I've tried using the regex below, but i only see the pattern and after the pattern returned:

```
filename = fl.replace(/(^.*?(?=[_]{1}[0-9]{1,10}))/gi, '');
```

- _962.jpg
- _0.jpg
- _1329317.jpg
- _29113.jpg

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In this case I would think it's more simpler, and faster (performance) to just use .lastIndexOf("_") to find the trailing part of the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
var repl = str.replace(/_\d+(?=\.jpg$)/, "");
```

**TESTING:**

```
str = 'eng_somerset_yeovil_montacute-house_962.jpg';
var repl = str.replace(/_\d+(?=\.jpg$)/, "");
// eng_somerset_yeovil_montacute-house.jpg
```